# jquery contents return prevObject in empty tag

Tags: jquery

let say I have the following markup:

```
<tr>
    <td>Yamaha 125 RR</td>
    <td>PJ/1010/2015</td>
    <td>2015-11-18</td>
    <td>2015-11-20</td>
    <td id="this-is-empty"></td>
    <td>Gear 1</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>action</td>
</tr>
```

when I do `$('#this-is-empty').contents()` it return prevObject, instead of something that I expect (I am trying to get native JS property, like `nodeValue`, `nodeType`, etc). is that so, or is there something wrong with my code?

**## UPDATE ##**

anyway, the actual code is:

```
var td = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(i);
var content = td.contents();
```

where `$(this)` refer to a button in `actions` column.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `HTML DOM` object for that to achieve.

```
document.getElementById('this-is-empty'); //returns a HTML DOM Object

var contents = $('#this-is-empty');  //returns a jQuery Object
```

In jQuery, to get the same result as document.getElementById, you can access the jQuery Object and get the first element in the object (Remember JavaScript objects act similar to associative arrays).

```
var contents = $('#this-is-empty')[0]; //returns a HTML DOM Object
```

Answer (score 0):

`#this-is-empty` has no children or text nodes, so `contents().length` is zero.  (Interesting the jQuery returns something called "prevObject," but you can ignore that.)

To get the `nodeValue` or `nodeType` of the `td`, do this:

```js
console.log($('#this-is-empty')[0].nodeValue);  //null
console.log($('#this-is-empty')[0].nodeType);   //1
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Yamaha 125 RR</td>
    <td>PJ/1010/2015</td>
    <td>2015-11-18</td>
    <td>2015-11-20</td>
    <td id="this-is-empty"></td>
    <td>Gear 1</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>action</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```